# How to make ST_DWithin to use meters for distance in Postgis?

Tags: postgis

I have already asked a similar question here:

[Find the nearest geo points across two tables with Postgis (or without)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182839/find-the-nearest-geo-points-across-two-tables-with-postgis-or-without)

but now I am stuck around the correct geo-reference to calculate the distance in ST_DWithin. What I have did with my tables is creating a column `geom` in this way:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 4326);
update my_table set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 4326);
CREATE INDEX my_table_geom_idx ON my_table USING gist(geom);
```

Using this setup will take the function `ST_DWithin` to use as distance parameter "degrees" instead of "meters".
How can I set the `geom` to work with meters? Is this the right setup?

```
ALTER TABLE my_table ADD COLUMN geom geometry(Point, 2163);
update my_table set geom = ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(longitude, latitude), 2163);
CREATE INDEX my_table_geom_idx ON my_table USING gist(geom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast the type to geography,

```
SELECT ST_AsText(geom)
FROM table
WHERE ST_DWithin( geom::geography, ... )
```

Consider setting the type on the table to geography too.